# Keeping dataframe column labels after subsetting

Tags: r, dplyr

Hope all is well during those weird times.

I am working with a dataframe, data is loaded from an SPSS file using the read.spss function.

In the original dataframe, I have column names and labels.

When I create a new dataframe based on the first one with some columns that I subset, the labels disapear.

This is what I use for subsetting:

```
test <- dataset %>% dplyr::select(GLOBAL_ID)
```

How could I make sure to keep them?

Thanks for the feedback !

Comment: Can you provide `dput(head(dataset))` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Would love, but when I do it on the 33956 variables R is going crazy ...

Comment: I can't reproduce this when I use example from `?haven::read_sas` help page. Labels are still intact with `dplyr::select`. Maybe you have data of different type.

Comment: @RonakShah Indeed this works great, but when loading the file, the read_sas function messes up with the values in the columns, for instance transforming the yes/no into 1 and 2, do you have any options to keep this normal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sjlabelled` to copy the labels back in e.g.

```
library(sjlabelled)
data(efc)
efc.sub <- subset(efc, subset = e16sex == 1, select = c(4:8))
#labels removed

#copy labels back in
efc.sub <- copy_labels(efc.sub, efc)
```

this is explained [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjlabelled/vignettes/labelleddata.html).